# Effect of storing self into a constant

Tags: ruby

```
class Employee
  EMP = []
  attr_reader :name, :hobbies, :friends

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @hobbies = []
    @friends = []
    EMP << self
  end
end
```

Can we discuss what happens at this line please: `EMP << self` ?
Obviously an element is added to the existing array (the array called EMP) - that is what is implied by the `<<` symbol.
But, which is the element that is added? Is it only `@name` and do we know it is only the `@name`  variable because it is the only argument from the `initialize` method?
What if the initialize method had **2 arg**:

```
def initialize(name, hob)
  @name = name
  @hobbies = hob
  @friends = []
  EMP << self
end
```

What would then be the effect of `EMP << self`? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The keyword `self` inside an instance method is a reference to the current object. So you are adding the object that is being intialized to the `EMP` array of the object itself (a thing that doesn't really make sense!).

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: @sawa I've added an answer below, check it out please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading constant from class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031060/reading-constant-from-class)

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `self` inside an instance method is a reference to the current object. So you are adding the object that is being intialized to the `EMP` array of <s>the object itself - a thing that doesn't really make sense!.</s> the class `Employee`.

<s>You may want to add the object to a class variable, which can be defined this way:</s>

```
class Employee
 @@EMP = []

 def initialize(name)
  @name = name
  @hobbies = []
  @friends = []
  @@EMP << self
 end
end
```

Thus, every time a new object is initialized, it's added to the `@@EMP` array of the class itself.

Comment: You did not answer why it does not make sense.

Comment: @sawa it doesn't make sense to have a `foo` employee that has an `EMP` array which contains a single element which is in truth a reference to `foo` itself.

Comment: That is not what it is doing.

Comment: Sawa, can you elaborate on what this/explain why you don't agree with the previous post?

Comment: @Sam I thought that `EMP` in your code only exists inside the current object, which is wrong because it exists inside the class itself. The difference between `EMP` and `@@EMP` (as far as I understand) is that `EMP` only exists in the current class, while `@@EMP` exists in the current class and all classes inherited from it.

Comment: I've edited my answer since @sawa deleted his one, it's not a good idea to have a single wrong answer on a question :3