# Reading constant from class

Tags: ruby

```
class Employee
    EMP = []
    attr_reader :name, :hobbies, :friends

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @hobbies = []
        @friends = []
        EMP << self
    end
end

em = Employee.new("Joe")
em2 = Employee.new("Blake")
```

If I try:
   `p em2.EMP` or `p em2.EMP[1]`
I get

> "undef meth EMP for #

If I try
`p Employee.EMP`

> I get "undef meth EMP for Person:Class..."

What is the right syntax to get the EMP value?
Thank you.

Comment: Indeed I see no PEOPLE anywhere...

Comment: possible duplicate of [effect of Constant array << self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030227/effect-of-constant-array-self)

Comment: Apologies for the confusion in my question, I corrected it.

Comment: Sawa, this question has a different flavour. In the other one I inquired about the significance of the EMP << self syntagm, whereas here I didn't know how to reference a class constant. Chandra and Sty explained the syntax for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want

```
p Employee::EMP
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Employee::EMP`.